# Listing all possible packages, not just those installed

Tags: meteor

I would like to look at a list of all possible packages at the command line, from which I can choose which ones I would like to install.

This used to be possible using the `meteor list` command, but now that command only lists installed packages.

Comment: `meteor list` used to list every default packages, which was reasonable because there was only 20 or so. Why not using `meteor search` or https://atmospherejs.com/ ?

Comment: because I don't know what I want to search for.  I guess I will try browsing atmospherejs